# Android notifications : best coding practices to display notifications to the most users?

Tags: java, android, push-notification, notifications, android-notifications

I implemented notifications in my app using FirebaseMessagingService and the Notification class.

My problem is that it seems that the notifications are displayed only to a small fraction of my user base. Indeed, when I compare:

- the number of active installs given by Google Play developer console
- and the number of notifications displayed every day according to Firebase analytics and Firebase Cloud Messaging reports

it seems that only 3% of installed apps receive the notifications. It seems very low. I expected at least 90% as I don't think that the users take time to disable the notifications in my app and that only a few remove the notifications in their phone settings.

Questions:

- what is the usual display ratio that should be reached with notifications ?
- what are the best practices (code, etc...) to maximize this ratio ?

Thanks.

Comment: how are you sending the notificationIf you dont use the `data` field in your payload to FCM then your notification will only be seen when your app is in the foreground

Comment: I use this method : https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref Yes, I use the data field. I receive the notifications on my device (and any test device) even when the app is in background (and even after phone restart). So I don't understand why so few devices receive my notifications.

Comment: How do you send them exactly? registration_ids has a limit of 1000. If you have more you need to send multiple requests to FCM